# What is steam app 210890?

Tags: steam

I just browsed through my steam games library and saw 'Steam App 210890' as something I could install. When I tried to install it,  to see what it was, steam told me that it would be downloading now, yet nothing happened.

Now I'm just wondering, what is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the situation described in [this post](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=30512732&postcount=1) and [a reply to a similar question](http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showpost.php?p=37382620&postcount=14187) to which [that user confirmed the same situation](http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showpost.php?p=37389672&postcount=14197), **this seems to be a Steam bug related to the newest patch of Crusader Kings II**.

Comment: Yeah, I do own Crusader Kings 2...